# Was Svetlana Khodchenkova's voice dubbed?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, the-wolverine

[image: Viper] <sup>[[Source](http://www.ew.com/ew/gallery/0,,20647938_20684746,00.html#21298603)]</sup>

I have read several reviews of [**The Wolverine**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1430132/) that believe russian actress [Svetlana Khodchenkova](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svetlana_Khodchenkova), who plays ***Viper***, was dubbed ([example](http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/the-wolverine-2013)), but [**IMDb**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1430132/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast) doesn't list a voice actress.

There is a *comment* on a [***Slashfilm.com*** article](http://www.slashfilm.com/the-wolverine-what-did-you-think/#comment-978008602) that claims:

> *I heard from a studio exec that worked on the film that **everyone was quite unhappy with Svetlana Khodchenkova's performance. They dubbed over all of her lines**, and drastically cut down her role in the final cut.*

**My Question:**

- Is there any official *(director, producer, the actress herself,...)* confirmation that *Svetlana Khodchenkova* was dubbed?

  If yes, who was the voice actress?

Comment: She was!!! But I don't think she's credited. You can hear in the trailer, she does have a different voice. (go to about 1:57 mins in) http://youtu.be/th1NTVIhUQU First time I saw the movie- I wondered if she was dubbed. The quality of her audio just seemed different... Still though it's definitely one of the better dubbing jobs I've seen- er HEARD! ;D

Comment: We need a bit more proof than just your opinion. -1

Comment: I believe the woman who provided the VoiceOver is the same who did the voice of Mandy at the costume party in Eyes Wide Shut.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any information about whether her voice was really dubbed. All the official forums and canon do not have any source on this. However, the general community consensus on the issue is *yes*, her voice was dubbed.

It does seem that way as the voice-over parts seem to dubbed pre-production. But if that really was the case, we do not have a source to confirm that.

Answer (score 0):

Everyones voice in every movie is dubbed over in the studio during most scenes to make it sound better. Some lip-flap is common and doesnt mean it wasnt the actor dubbing themselves.

Comment: Please read the notice given below the question, and add details to your answer.

Comment: Yes, ADR is extremely common. The question is about whether or not her lines were re-recorded by someone *else*, similar to David Prowse/James Earl Jones in *Star Wars*